# Remember fields across pages?

Tags: php, input, field, remember-me

I have this: 
main.php:

```
ID: <input name="id" id="id" type="text" size="20" value="<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>"><br>
Password: <input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>" size="20">
```

File main.php is index page.

File main.php is a form with action="main.php"

When i go from main.php to console.php, i dont get the values id and password.

When i go from main.php to plugins.php, i dont get the values id and password.

From main.php, you can get into plugins.php and console.php. But you don't get the values then.

I know why it happens.

How to fix this? How can i make, that when i go to console.php, or plugins.php, the fields will stay remembered?

Sessions are too hard for me to learn. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Sessions are not difficult. They will be a lot easier than passing these fields across pages

Comment: @Teoman Soygul So why suggest it then!?

Comment: @ILMV Actually you're right, I was just suggesting the lesser of two evils. Erased the comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too hard? Put simply, at the top of every page you want to use sessions with, use `session_start()`. Now, you want to save something to a session?

```
#page1
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

#page2
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['foo'] #echoes bar

unset($_SESSION['foo']); #destroy foo
#if you want to discard the entire session, use
session_destroy(); #going down!
```

So, in your case, maybe something like:

```
#main.php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
#rest of main.php

#console.php and plugins.php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['password']))
    #do stuff
```

I feel bad for spoon-feeding you with it, but basic session functionality is really all that's needed in the case you're describing, and it's probably the easiest way to pass around sensitive info, and is basically what sessions were made for.

For more info:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
- http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions

Comment: OMG THANKS! I wish i could give you some kind of point. (Too low rank :( )

Comment: No problem. And you can give points to the correct answerer; by accepting the answer (clicking on the empty tick sign next to the answer) and up-voting answers (requires 15 rep, and done by clicking up-arrow next to the answer.) Looked at your other questions, and you should do that to the answers there if there's anything you found useful.

Comment: Also, just as a general comment: Never give up on learning something. Even if it looks like the hardest thing ever, if it's interesting, it's worth it. Making a simple html web-page looked excruciating until you learn how it's done. Plus, it makes you look oh-so-cool to use the big-boy's toys.

Answer (score 1):

1) Learn sessions.  And never pass around someone's password.  You should hash the password, and check it against a hashed value in your database.  When you have checked for a match, you can store in your session variables that the user is authenticated - you no longer need to know which password they submitted.

2) Understand that when you submit an html form, the `action` of the form is the only page that can do anything directly with the posted form parameters.

...

Try not to give up on learning these things - they were created to make your life easier, not more challenging.

[Example PHP authentication classes for you to use](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/simple-php-login-class.php)

Comment: Is there any other way how i can make it remember fields across pages?

Comment: The easiest way is with sessions.  If you don't use them, then you'd have to pass the parameters to every page the user navigated to (either by yet another form, or by adding information onto every link).